# How can I install Maglev with rvm on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, maglev

I am trying to install Maglev on Mac OS X Lion with rvm, but running

```
rvm install maglev
```

as instructed on the github page only yields a 404 error:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
ERROR: The requested url does not exist: 'http://glass-downloads.gemstone.com/maglev/MagLev-26852.Darwin-i386.tar.gz'
```

which does not seem too helpful, as it just points out that the respective file does not exist on the gemstone server. Google does not seem to know about this, so I thought about asking a question here. However, before doing so I tried some more and and got a little further running

```
 rvm install maglev-head
```

as mentioned in some blog posts. This finally finds an appropriate file, downloads a bunch of things and starts to compile. It starts to look really well at a point where it says

```
 Installing maglev to /[user-dir]/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head
```

in green, but unfortunately it does not get much further. The installation hangs after saying

```
Creating default 'maglev' repository.
Generating maglev HTML documentation
Generating smalltalk FFI.
```

or at least it takes forever (more than 30 minutes) without saying anything.

Stopping the installation at this point still looks promising giving me

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   maglev-head [ x86_64 ]
```

but unfortunately

```
rvm use maglev-head
```

results in

```
startstone[Info]: Starting Stone repository monitor 'maglev'.

startstone[Error]: Stone process (id=61119) has died.
startstone[Error]: Examine '/[user-dir]/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/log/maglev/maglev.log' for more information.  Excerpt follows:
```

without displaying an excerpt and even without stopping. Actually the log file does exist and has a few error messages, the most telling seems to be

```
GemStone is unable to open the file !TCP@localhost6#dbf!/[user-dir]/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/data/maglev/extent/extent0.ruby.dbf
```

but the directory does exist, it would just be the file that is missing, and I would expect the server to create that one on an new image. Still, the situation does not look too bad as i get

```
which irb
```

giving me

```
/[user-dir]/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/bin/irb
```

but when I try to start up irb I get

```
maglev-ruby: [Error] The MagLev server "maglev" is not running.
To fix this run "rake maglev:start" before running maglev-ruby.
```

but if I call the rake task as instructed I again get

```
maglev-ruby: [Error] The MagLev server "maglev" is not running.
To fix this run "rake maglev:start" before running maglev-ruby.
```

putting me in a recursive causality loop. Trying to start the maglev server by hand using

```
 maglev start
```

as I did on a previous installation using the shell scripts does not work either, giving me

```
 startstone[Info]: Starting Stone repository monitor 'maglev'.

 startstone[Error]: Stone process (id=61400) has died.
 startstone[Error]: Examine '/[user-dir]/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/log/maglev/maglev.log' for more information.  Excerpt follows:
```

again without displaying an excerpt and hanging.

Any help would be appreciated as Maglev looks like a really promising piece of infrastructure.

Comment: Hmm. It's working fine for me, and I'd say the install happened in < 10 minutes.

Comment: I tried to reinstall maglev, uninstalling it through `rvm uninstall maglev-head` first, but that did not work properly either. I had to manually remove the `maglev-head` and `GemStone...` directories from `.rvm/src` before the install ran again. Unfortunately the install again hang for quite some time on `Generating smalltalk FFI.`, though this time it finished, but again my Stone process died. Examining `~/.rvm/rubies/maglev-head/log/maglev/maglev.log` again told me little, as the required file `extent0.ruby.dbf` should be created by the server on startup (and permissions allow this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do "rvm get head" first; I can see it was looking for MagLev-26852.Darwin-i386.tar.gz, which was for an older version both of MagLev and of RVM.

I'd do an "rvm remove maglev; rvm install maglev" It shouldn't take more than a few minutes then  to build once it's downloaded.

Comment: If you can't get that to work, try the "Install from GitHub" instructions on http://maglev.github.com/docs/download.html.

Comment: Thanks Monty, I just figured this out from your comments on github, obviously my "old" (that is 10 days old ...) version of rvm did not cut it. As I tried to `uninstall` instead of `remove` maglev I again had to remove `maglev-head` and `GemStone...` manually from the `src`, but I am sure your solution would have fixed it more easily.